# Get point of collision from Physics.ComputePenetration()

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-physics, physics-engine, physx

I have a very basic player in Unity that I coded to collide against objects using `Physics.ComputePenetration(...)` and it works relatively well. The problem is that I would like more detailed information about *where* the player hit the collider.

**Some things to note:**

First of all, the idea of this project is to see if I can replicate the `CharacterController`'s functionality from scratch using `ComputePenetration`. I am currently trying to replicate the built-in `OnControllerColliderHit(...)` function, which allows me to get the location of where the hit took place.

Second of all, I am not using a `SphereCollider`. If I was, then all I would have to do is get the returned `direction` vector and multiply it by the sphere's radius (along with a couple of other things). But sadly, I am using a `CapsuleCollider` (maybe there's a way to do the same thing but for a `CapsuleCollider`, but I have not been able to find one).

**What I've tried:**

My initial idea was to take the collider that the player hit, `hitCollider`, and execute this snippet of code:

```
Vector3 point = hitCollider.ClosestPoint(player.transform.position);
```

to get the closest point on the hit collider. From there, I could call

```
Vector3 finalPoint = player.collider.ClosestPoint(point);
```

on the player to get *its* closest point to the hit collider's closest point. It's very confusing, but it works pretty well. There's only one drawback, however: I plan on using ProBuilder to do a lot of my level design, and you cannot call `ClosestPoint` on a `MeshCollider` that does not have `convex` set to true, which is a majority of meshes in ProBuilder.

I thought of a couple of other things, like maybe I could invert the direction and then do some (not-so) hacky math to get the contact point, etc. but nothing seemed to work as a full-blown solution.

**Closing thoughts:**

I'm beginning to think that it's not technically possible. Which is true if you think about it, because when two objects intersect, there's no single *point* that defines it, it's an entire *volume* that does so. But getting the average position of that volume would (maybe?) be the solution.

Any ideas?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: I thought the collision included the extract hit point.

Comment: @BugFinder It doesn't, sadly. Only a direction and a distance needed to depenetrate the colliders

Comment: Really? So what about the contact points that it gives which are the points on the collider. When using oncollision  it has the points. Are you not reinventing the wheel?

Comment: Its seems that you are trying to build your own custom physics calculation while still using Unity's out of the box capabilities. Unity already provides this functionality using [collision contacts](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Collision-contacts.html)

Comment: @BugFinder I'm trying to, yeah, but OnCollisionEnter is only called by objects that come in contact with Rigidbodies and Rigidbodies themselves. And since Unity is closed source, I can't see how they do it

Comment: @ErikOverflow It's not that simple though. My player doesn't call OnCollisionEnter unless it comes across a Rigidbody. Otherwise, collisions are pretty much ignored. That's why Physics.ComputePenetration is needed to depenetrate the character, because Unity won't do it for me

Comment: Why aren't you just assigning a kinematic RigidBody to your player? The literal purpose of a RigidBody is to enable collision detection.

Comment: @ErikOverflow Kinematic Rigidbodies don't detect collision by default. The only way to do that is to click "Enable All Contacts" in the Physics settings, but I don't want that because that would mean that ALL Kinematic Rigidbodies have collisions now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For anyone else who was curious, I found the solution. When `Physics.ComputePenetration(...)` between `ourCollider` and `selectedCollider` detects a collision, make sure to de-penetrate FIRST, then do the following:

Call a `Physics.CapsuleCast(...)`, but make sure that `point1`, `point2`, and `radius` are slightly smaller values (maybe 0.001) than the original capsule's size. This is because the `CapsuleCast` will think that it's intersecting with the `selectedCollider` and will therefore just go straight through it, which you don't want. Then just make your `direction` the negative direction that was output from `Physics.ComputePenetration(...)`.

So your code ends up looking like this:

```
var origin = this.transform.position + this.center;
var offset = new Vector3(0.0f, this.height / 2.0f - this.radius - someTinyValue, 0.0f);
if (Physics.CapsuleCast(
        origin + offset,
        origin - offset,
        this.radius - someTinyValue,
        -direction,
        out var hit))
{
    // Do whatever with the `hit` variable
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This method works pretty good but can be slow a bit. (At least i sometimes see momentary intersections)

```
public bool IsGrounded { get; set; } = true;
private void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
{   
    if (other.CompareTag(_groundTagName))
    {
        IsGrounded = true;
        _landingSpeed = _fireSpeed;

        if(_IsPhysicsComputePenetration == true)
        {   //Here is the exact point to calculate intersection level
            //Player collider and transformation infos, other collider and transformation infos required to find exact intersection vector and scale
            Physics.ComputePenetration(_collider, transform.position, transform.rotation,
                       other, other.transform.position, other.transform.rotation,
                       out _penetrationDirection, out _penetrationDistance);
            Debug.Log("Grounded!");
            AlignGameObjectToSurfaceAfterCollision();
        }

    }
}

private void AlignGameObjectToSurfaceAfterCollision()
{   
    transform.position += _penetrationDirection * _penetrationDistance;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried using the existing Collider.ClosestPoint, and using the position of the object subtracted by the penetration distance (scaled up so it's far away enough from the collider's inside) and that seems to work well:

```
Vector3 collisionPoint = myCollider.ClosestPoint(collidingObject.transform.position - (penetrationDirection * 5f));
```